# How to get Scrapy's SitemapSpider to crawl at depth greater than 1?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to record every link that occurs within a site. I am using the SitemapSpider, but viewing the resulting CSV shows that the Spider never acheives a depth further than 1 - I want it to follow each link it encounters and scrape the links from those as well. Depth limit is supposed to be unlimited by default, but I added a DEPTH_LIMIT of 5 to settings.py as a test and it had no effect.

(Additionally, the "other_urls" stipulation seems to have no effect - no results from that URL show up in the CSV.)

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import fffItem
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider

class fffSpider(SitemapSpider):
    name = "fff_sitemap"
    sitemap_urls = ["http://fff.com/sitemap.xml"]
    other_urls = ["http://www.fff.com/fff/default.aspx"]


    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        for sel in response.xpath('//a'):
            item = fffItem()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
            item['sourceurl'] = response.url
            item['depth'] = response.meta['depth']
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

I am fairly new to Scrapy/Python in general, and looked at answered questions involving SitemapSpider, but they either didn't apply or I didn't fully understand them. Apologies if this is a repeat.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [`sitemap_follow`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=sitemap#scrapy.spiders.SitemapSpider.sitemap_follow) class argument.
By default all of sitemap links are followed so the depth is maximum possible.